# Creating an Expandable Top Bar Menu with Tree Structure for Folders and (mayby) Image Previews in Ubuntu

Tags: menu, customization, hud, top-bar

I don't embrace linux and ubuntu very much.
My question is **simple**. Is there a way to add on the top menu bar in the style of the existing "Applications" menu. So that it can be expanded. My goal is to create a tree of folders with images in them. It would be cool if when you hover over such an image it would display a preview of the image on the right :)
Something like this:

[image: Something like this]

Edit:
My Ubuntu Release: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
My Desktop Environment: GNOME

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question and add details a) which Ubuntu release you are using and b) which desktop environment. Especially information on the latter is important to know in order to see whether there is possibly a solution for your problem.

Comment: would it not be easier to use a filemanager (and maybe a script for the previews?)  Maybe this for nemo: https://github.com/linuxmint/nemo-extensions/tree/master/nemo-preview ?

Comment: @noisefloor done

Comment: @Rinzwind It's just a crazy person's idea :) I would prefer this way

Comment: IMHO there is not easy way to do that. May be possibe writing an extension for GNOME.